# Drive-By Deletion of Answer to Own Question by Moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I'm a bit confused by some moderator action. I posted a question [asking for a direct proof of a certain fact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451864/direct-proof-of-unique-invariant-distribution-for-ergodic-positive-recurrent-ma). A superb [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451868/509687) was provided by Jochen Glueck. (Thanks again!)

I came across another proof by chance in some lecture notes I was reading. I felt the appropriate thing was to copy (with citation!) that proof into another answer. Sure, it didn't help *me*, but MO is more than just "user asks question; user gets answer; bye bye". I wanted to share this for the benefit of the community.

I happen to look at the question again today, and I see that a moderator deleted my answer. They didn't comment on it, suggesting improvement. Just a drive-by delete. Putting aside the rudeness/disrespect/whatever-word-you-want*,

> What was the reason for this deletion? and, why was there no communication?

Are self-answers no longer encouraged? Certainly I'm not encouraged to support the community given this treatment.

*It's fairly well established that this sort of behaviour is what has driven many people away from the Stack Exchanged sites. I used to be fairly active, with >5k rep gained via answers over a few years, but packed it in, barely posting questions or answers now, largely due to this sort of behaviour

Comment: this was quite possibly a mistaken deletion, I would just flag it to the moderators, and I'm sure it will be resolved; mistakes happen, I would not read too much into this.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks, have done. I appreciate that people were working quickly to get through a large backlog, and mistakes do happen

Comment: Deletion of answers seems like quite a big deal, though, so perhaps there should be a check in place; eg, maybe an answer is "proposed for deletion", then is only deleted if another mod confirms this. Of course, this adds _more_ work for the (volunteer) mods...

Comment: "I see that a moderator deleted my question." I don't see that, at all. I see that a moderator deleted your *answer*. Maybe because your answer ended with several questions, indicating that it wasn't complete?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5748/drive-by-deletion-of-answer-to-own-question-by-moderator#comment29026_5748), since the rest of the post shows that ‘question’ there was certainly a mis-type for ‘answer’, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, thank you! My apologies. As per the *title*, and the *self-answer* reference, it was indeed the *answer* which was deleted. Writing *question* in the body was a typo. Thank you, LSpice, for correcting this 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My apologies for the mistaken deletion of your answer. —  What led to this mistake was a combination of several circumstances: it was a self-answer of an anonymous user which got flagged as "not an answer" and which had questions at the end, and it had neither upvotes nor comments. Sorry again.

Comment: All good, mistakes happen. We live and learn! Particularly easy when clearly large backlog—which, incidentally, was done extremely promptly by the mods, in my view. [PS. I thought I had already written this in a comment, but it's not there any more... maybe it was removed or maybe I'm going insane!]